# Proguard - removing logs roboguice.util.Ln

Tags: android, proguard, roboguice

In my app we are using logs from roboguice.util.Ln. I read how to remove logging by using proguard, but it seems to not working on roboguice logging. The last thing i tried was to add in my proguard configuration file something like this:

```
-assumenosideeffects class roboguice.util.Ln {
  public static *** v(...);
  public static *** i(...);
  public static *** w(...);
  public static *** d(...);
  public static *** e(...);

  public static boolean isDebugEnabled();

  public static boolean isVerboseEnabled();
}

-assumenosideeffects class roboguice.util.Ln$Print {
  public int println(int, java.lang.String);
  protected java.lang.String processMessage(java.lang.String);
  protected static java.lang.String getScope(int);
}
```

I also tried to do this without adding Print inner class, methods is***Enabled() etc. Any ideas how to remove roboguice.util.Ln logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration for `roboguice.util.Ln` looks correct. However, the option `-assumenosideeffects` only has effect with optimization enabled. In Android builds this means: in release mode and with the shared configuration `proguard-android-optimize.txt` in `project.properties` for Ant, or `build.gradle` for Gradle.